# PHP: How can I add newly one row at the top of the csv file using fputcsv?

Tags: php, fputcsv

I want how can I add newly one new row at the top of the csv file becase in my csv file output its populated with data from database and what I want to happen is that I want to add corresponding column names for every type of data.

Here is my code as of now:

```
    <?php
include 'database.php';
$db = new database();

$data = $db->exportdatabase();

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($data as $items)
{
    fputcsv($file, $items, ',');
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
header("Expires: 0");
fclose($file);
exit;
?>
```

Here is my csv data looks like

[Image](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/2546/12641493y.png)

Comment: What's the problem? Write the line of column names before the foreach loop.

Comment: that's my problem I don't know how? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try before foreach set column names

Or using `fseek` function

```
fseek($file, 0);
fputcsv($file, $titles, ',');
```

[fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) Seeks on a file pointer

Comment: Can you seek in `php://output`? It doesn't point to a file. But why do you need to seek? Just do it before writing the data.

Comment: where should i put my title? for example i have a column name of "ID", "BRAND", "PRICE" and etc..? where should i put that got confused. thanks!

Comment: @MekeniKine $columns = array('id', 'brand', 'price', ...); before foreach loop put this array to output, like this: `fputcsv($file, $columns, ',');`

Comment: @Barmar I just provide an example. :)