# Use fputcsv() to insert a row at the top of a csv file?

Tags: php, csv

Pretty simple question. I know how to use `fputcsv()` to insert a row into a csv but it inserts it at the bottom. Is there a way to use it to insert something at the top of the csv?

I need to add a header to an existing csv file.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`fputcsv()` inserts data at the file pointer, so you can [rewind()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.rewind.php) the pointer to the beginning of the file.

```
rewind($handle);
fputcsv($handle, $fields);
```

Alternately, you can simply open the file with the pointer at the beginning:

```
$handle = fopen('yourfile.csv', 'r+');
fputcsv($handle, $fields);
```

Comment: @Geoarge-Cummins Going by what I know from C/C++ and the concept of files, I don't think this will work either. Rather, it may REPLACE the first record. I haven't tried this have you?

Comment: @itsols Yes, I have. PHP allows you to select whether to modify existing contents or overwrite when you `fopen()` a file. As long as you don't use the `w` modes, data will be prepended/appended rather than obliterating existing content.

Comment: Thanks for the help. rewind() is still inserting at the end. Opening the file with r+ is putting it at the beginning but it's writing over the first line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Basically with:

```
fseek($file, 0);
fputcsv($file, $titles, ',');
```

I think this is duplicate for [PHP: How can I add newly one row at the top of the csv file using fputcsv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514069/php-how-can-i-add-newly-one-row-at-the-top-of-the-csv-file-using-fputcsv)

Comment: Are you SURE? From what I know this may write the new data replacing the first record. NOT inserting.